# IIS Created (201) Response Compression

Tags: iis

I have found that IIS 10 is not compressing responses with a 201 status code. Has anyone found a solution for this? This document seems to suggest it was a feature of II 6/7.5:
[IIS Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-iis-compression-issues-in-iis6-iis7x)

Comment: You have post the question on Microsft Q&A. So I will continue to discuss with you in Q&A.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the HTTP specification ([POST](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#POST)), returning a 201 is incorrect if the body of the response contains the created entity instead of links to it. In this light, the behaviour of IIS is entirely reasonable.